# Remove duplicates from sorted array in C++

Tags: c++, vector, duplicates, sorting

> ##### Remove duplicates from Sorted Array
>
> Given a sorted array, remove the duplicates in place such that each element appears only once and return the new length.
>
> Note that even though we want you to return the new length, make sure to change the original array as well in place
>
> Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this in place with constant memory.

I tried following code, where am I going wrong?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int removeDuplicates(vector<int> &A) {
    int m=A.size();
    if(m<=1) return m;
    vector<int> :: iterator i=A.begin();
    vector<int> :: iterator j=A.begin()+1;
    vector<int> :: iterator temp;
    while(i!=A.end() && j!=A.end())
    {
        while(j!=A.end() && *i == *j)
        {
            temp=j;
            j++;
            A.erase(temp);
        }
        i=j;
        j++;
    }
    return A.size();
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,7,7,7,7,9};
    cout<<"ans="<<removeDuplicates(vec);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what is the result of the program? What is the expected result? Have you tried to step through the code line by line in a debugger, to see what happens?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel.  Use [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) and [`std::vector::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase).  The link for `std::unique` even shows how this is done.

Comment: After call of `erase` all vector's iterators became invalid. You better work with indices

Comment: @ Joachim Pileborg : I tried debugging to my best, inserting so many print statements here and there, still couldn't detect where I am going wrong!!, FOr Posting the code, I removed comments to make it clearer

Comment: @NathanOliver: I didn't get you?

Comment: @ Semyon Burov: thanks, I will try that, but can't it be done using itertors anyway??

Comment: @user6038386 What don't you get?  Instead of trying to do this yourself use the built in standard functions that will do it for you.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I assume, it is an assingment (or an interview question).

Comment: @SergeyA Nothing I proposed violates the constraints in the question.

Comment: @NathanOliver, agreed. But possibly violates the spirit of it :) It is actually a good interview question, I believe, i used it a couple of times. I would not accept `std::unique` as an answer (but candidate would get a plus point for knowing it)

Comment: @SergeyA: you are right, surely `std::unique` was addition yo my knowledge, but its a potential interview question, where this will not help!!

Answer (score 1):

When you increment `j`, then `erase` the element there, the elements starting at j+1 are moved down. You're skipping over an element by incrementing.

A better approach would be to simply copy the non-repeating elements from one iterator to the other and setting the new length at the end of the main loop. Your current approach is potentially O(n^2), too slow for practical use.

Comment: whatever you told is perfectly correct...it works if I put  **j=A.erase(j)**  in place of  **temp=j; j++; A.erase(temp);**  .....but I still couldn't understand how i am skipping over an element by incrementing

Comment: potentially how `j=A.erase(j)` is different from `temp=j; j++; A.erase(temp);` ??

Answer (score 0):

You are asked to use an array. Although vector is similar in many ways, it is not the same. Have a look at the example code below.

In addition you are asked to keep memory allocated the same. You cannot ensure that using vector, it's size can grow / shrink once you add / remove elements and when an element is removed the data in the array behind the vector will be reallocated and rewritten.

```
int main()
{

    int arr[14] = {0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,7,9};
    int last_non_duplicate_index = 0;
    int current_index = 0;
    int size = 14;
    int new_size = size;
    bool is_last_value = false;

    // you can use for interchangeably
    while(!is_last_value)
    {
        current_index++; // move one position ahead
        if(current_index < size) // out of bonds check
        {
            if(arr[last_non_duplicate_index] != arr[current_index]) // value at position of current index is different
            {
                last_non_duplicate_index++; // increase index of the last value which was not a duplicate by one
                arr[last_non_duplicate_index] = arr[current_index]; // write at that index 
                // e.g. if last index was 0 -> increase it to 1 and rewrite whatsever under arr[1] (current index)
            }
            else // values are the same
            { 
                new_size--; // devrease the size
            }
        }
        else
        {
            is_last_value = true; // current_index >= size -> out of bonds
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < new_size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "arr[" << i << "]" << " = " << arr[i] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "New size: " << new_size << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is that you need. This func loops array from tail to head and counts same values. Then performs shift of already unique values on ununique one.
It doesn't change actual size of vector due process because it would probably involve reallocation of memory inside of vector.

```
int removeDuplicates(vector<int> &vec) {
    int currentVal = vec.size() - 1;
    int uniqueNumber = 0;

    while (currentVal >= 0) {
        ++uniqueNumber;
        int sameVal = currentVal;
        while (sameVal > 0 && vec[sameVal - 1] == vec[currentVal])
            --sameVal;

        int shiftSize = uniqueNumber;
        for (int k = 1; k < shiftSize; ++k) {
            vec[sameVal + k] = vec[currentVal + k];
        }

        currentVal = sameVal - 1;
    }
    return uniqueNumber;
}
```

Comment: This has a subtle bug.  If the maximum value of `std::vector::size_type` is larger than the maximum value of `int` then it is possible that `currentVal = vec.size() - 1;` can be UB as you overflow `currentVal`.  This is also true if an 0 sized vector is passed.

Comment: The problem in question looks like homework, so I used more student like type `int`. Changing `int` to `std::ptrdiff_t` should solve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using iterators like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int removeDuplicates(vector<int> &A) {
    int m = A.size();
    if(m <= 1) return m;

    for (auto it1 = A.begin(); it1 != A.end(); it1++) {
        for (auto it2 = it1 + 1; it2 != A.end();) {
            if (*it1 == *it2) {
                it2 = A.erase(it2);
            } else {
                it2++;
            }
        }
    }

    return A.size();
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9 };
    cout << "ans=" << removeDuplicates(vec);
    return 0;
}
```